# Is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, closing-questions

I have asked about the disadvantage of hyperplanes for the linear congruent random number generator, and [the post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38328/hyperplane-problem-in-linear-congruent-generator) has received 4 votes as off-topic, one away from being closed. So I wonder if the closed votes are unreasonable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, basically pseudorandom generators are a topic for either discrete mathematics (theoretical part) or something I used to call "computational science" (practical part) -- there is a SE for both ([Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [SciComp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)).

Your question seems to be more theoretical, so it might get a better attention on Math.SE; in fact this is what close-voters think.